# How to sum up all variables in a single column in R

Tags: r

I have an file in that one particular column I have 3 variables like supermarket, grocery & ball. I need to sum up all these names to find their total number how to  do that with code in R language

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Is this what you want ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Comment: search on aggregate (for base R) or group_by (for tidyverse). This must be one of the mose frequently asked questions by new users of R. You should only [edit] your question if your searching is unsuccessful.

Comment: library(vcd)
View(Arthritis)
re=Arthritis%>%
  group_by(Improved)%>%
  summarise(new_col_improved=n())
View(re)

use this function it will work especially to count all variables of a single column